# Stuck in bootloop after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, apt, fsck

I think the cause is a power shortage during the fsck/clean part where it only says 'dev/sda1/ : recovering journal' .

The computer will reach fsck clean and it'll say "recovering journals", so and so many files checked, the screen will flash and try to start Ubuntu and go right back, in an infinite loop.

I would assume something wasn't correctly written during shut down and that there are some corrupt files causing this.

I've tried going into **recovery** **mode** and doing everything there, `dpkg` repair and `clean` give me the error `apt-get: relocation error somename not defined in libstdc++.so.6`. `fsck` doesn't give any errors when in the recovery mode prompt. Unfortunately, my Ubuntu knowledge is limited, so do I have any options here? Do I have to reinstall my OS?

Comment: Your question title says that you are stuck in the boot process, but you managed to run `fsck` and even `apt-get`.  You will need to elaborate more, because your question is quite confusing right now.  Also, if you can run `apt-get` you should be able to get the output of `dmesg` which is very useful fro boot issues.

Comment: What? In recovery mode, trying to clean, dpkg repair causes apt-get relocation error. On running fsck in *recovery mode* everything is OK.